# Can't return object with belongsToMany relationship attached

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to return a list of `$users` with an array of roles.

Here's my controller:

```
    $users = DB::table('users')->take(5)->skip(2)->get();

    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        $user = User::with('roles')->find($user->id);
    }

    return Response::json(array(
        'users' => $users
    ));
```

And here's the model relationship:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Role')->withTimestamps();
}
```

But this just returns the users without the role attached to it. However, if I do this:

```
return Response::json(array(
    'users' => User::with('roles')->get()
));
```

I get the full list with the roles attached to each user. So, what am I doing wrong?

Oddly, if I do this:

```
return Response::json(array(
    'users' => User::with('roles')->find($user->id)
));
```

Then it returns that user with the roles as I expected, so why not return it in the `foreach` statement?

Comment: In your controller you are returning `$users`, the `foreach` loop does create instances of `User` in `$user` but those are not sent back in the response because they don't affect `$users` in any way. Hard to put into words, but do you understand that calling `User::with...` there has no impact whatsoever on the original `$users` array? (edit: what @lukasgeiter said in his answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loosing the whole Eloquent relations functionality when using `DB` queries.

You could just

```
$users = User::with('roles')->take(5)->skip(2)->get();
```

A good practice is to *not* mix Eloquent model "style" queries (`User::...->get()`) with direct DB queries (`DB::table('user')...->get`).

Answer (score 1):

The `foreach` uses **pass by value**. That means you are not changing the actual array item but just a copy of the value. To change that and get the item **passed by reference** add a `&`:

```
foreach ($users as &$user) {
    $user = User::with('roles')->find($user->id);
}
```

---

However why don't you just do it this way?

```
$users = User::with('roles')->take(5)->skip(2)->get();
return Response::json(array(
    'users' => $users
));
```